# SIGABRT (unrecognized selector) after trying to write NSData from a NSURLConnection to a file

Tags: iphone, ios, file, nsurlconnection, nsdata

---

**SOLVED:** the filename was an autoreleased string no longer available when called at createFileAtPath:

---

I'm trying to track the progress of the download of a file and the code I'm trying to implement is this **(edited)**:

```
 connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    if (connection)
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];    

    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];

    totalBytes = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]] intValue];
    NSLog(@"content-length: %i bytes", totalBytes);
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    int resourceLength = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[receivedData length]] intValue];
    NSLog(@"receivedData length: %i", resourceLength);
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [fileMgr createFileAtPath:filename contents:receivedData attributes:nil];

    //if instead i write only the Apple example:
    //NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    //there's no SIGABRT
    [receivedData release];
    [connection release];
}
```

but the createFileAtPath:contents:attributes: just gives SIGABRT:

> -[__NSCFData
>   getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x2ba510
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFData
>   getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x2ba510'

what am i doing wrong? isn't this the way to download a file asynchronously ?

2 more things: a) the content-length NSLog is correct. b) if I don't initWithCapacity:content-lenght in didReceiveResponse and just init, the receivedData length only grows about two times the content-length...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:** the filename was an autoreleased string no longer available when called at createFileAtPath:

Answer (score 1):

I can't possibly say it any better than in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) so I won't try. Follow through this guide and you should be solved.

As a side note there are a few memory problems in your code in this line

```
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[response expectedContentLength]];
```

You are creating an `NSMutableData` object with a retain count +1 and assuming you have appropriate getters/setters made using `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *recievedData` that will add an additional +1.

To resolve this either one of these two will work (the non auto released version is best for iphone).

```
NSMutableData *recievedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[response expectedContentLength]]; 
self.recievedData = recievedData;
[recievedData release]; recievedData= nil;

// or the autoreleased version
self.recievedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[response expectedContentLength]];
```

Additionally I would call

```
self.recievedData = nil;
```

instead of

```
[self.recievedData release];
```

As it seems a bit safer and you are using the setter which is a good practice to get into.

Comment: I've followed the guide actually... and even stripped down everything to look like the guide. The problem is when I wan't to createFileAtPath:... everything thing else works like a charm. I will edit the code above to reflect actual code.

Comment: Maybe try the built in method on `NSData` and `NSMutableData` by inheritance `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` to write the data out.